# What is the character used to indent the Make file rule recipe?

Tags: make, gnu

I am using gnu make and in a Makefile I have, I see below rule.
I want to add a similar rule with a recipe, but when I add a rule and its receipe on the next line by giving a tab or space for the recipe, I get make error.

```
dummy :
    @echo $(OBJS)
```

When i turned on the vim command :set list , i see:

```
dummy :$
^I@echo $(OBJS)$
```

What exactly are the characters before the recipe line(second line) which indent it from the start of line?

How do I enter them using keyboard (without having to copy paste the exisitng rule and then modifying it?

Where would I find information for various spaces/indents to be used in creating a Makefile from beginning, by hand(Not a automake/or other tool created makefile)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After picking some pointers from answer given by DMA57361 above, and some more fiddling, i noticed that long time back in my .vimrc I had this command  `set expandtab` (It expands tabs into spaces) and I use vim.

This was spoiling the Tab character which I was entering in my Makefile rules. Commenting that line in .vimrc helped and its working for me.

Answer (score 9):

Recipies in a makefile *must* be preceeded by a single standard `tab` character, nothing else.

`^I` is the representation of the tab character (see the table on the Wikipedia [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_control_characters) page), and therefore this should be correct.

So you should be able to enter it using <kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>.
(assuming these are not remapped by the software)

---

#### Edit

On further investigation it looks like you *can* change the character required to preceed all recipe lines from a tab by setting the `.RECIPEPREFIX` [special variable](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Special-Variables).

If this value has been defined in your makefile all recipes *after* the definition must use that character instead of a tab.

Comment: But when I do so with a TAB, for the recipe line, I keep getting a error when I do make , which says "Makefile:50: *** missing separator. Stop." at that line. Only when I copy some existing rule and use it, it goes through.

Comment: @goldenmean Looking at the [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Error-Messages) and searching for "missing seperator" gives `This means that make could not understand much of anything about the makefile line it just read. GNU make looks for various separators (:, =, recipe prefix characters, etc.) to indicate what kind of line it's parsing. This message means it couldn't find a valid one.` - maybe you need to remove the space between the job name and the colon?

Comment: @goldenmean - looking at the docs further it is apparently possibly to *change* the recipe prefix character from a tab by setting the `.RECIPEPREFIX` [special variable](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Special-Variables) - has these been defined in your makefile?

Answer (score 2):

In light of the accepted answer: recipes must be preceded by a `tab` character, which is automatically replaced if `set expandtab` is enabled in your `.vimrc`. Overwriting your `.RECIPEPREFIX` is not recommended, as this breaks makefiles in codebases you downloaded. The naive approach is to simply remove `set expandtab` from your configuration, but you can get around this by adding the line

`autocmd FileType make set tabstop=8 shiftwidth=8 softtabstop=0 noexpandtab`.

This disables `expandtab` only when you're editing a makefile.